# Need a good website URL to test against

Tags: testing, network-programming

I need a URL to just test basic http connectivity. It needs to be consistent and:

1. Always be up
2. Never change drastically due to IP or user agent. (IE: 301 Location redirect/ huge difference in content... minor would be tolerable)
3. The URL itself has a consistent content-length. (IE: it doesn't vary from by 2kb at most, ever)

A few examples, yet none match all 3 criteria:

- One example of always up: www.google.com (yet it 301 redirects based on IP location).
- Another good one is http://www.google.com/webhp?hl=en. but the problem there is that based on a given holiday, the content-length can really vary.

Comment: If you are testing http connectivity, why not just ping www.google.com?

Comment: I want to test if data can go over the pipe. And to be more specific, if I can get at least 5kb.

Comment: Did you try my last suggestion? Will always be the same, from anywhere in the world. A comment on my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not go to something like http://www.google.com/ncr? Then you won't be redirected

Comment: Looks good from here (America), but they do not redirect if you are from a non-english speaking country...?

Comment: Try my edit! :) Always redirect to the english version of www.google.com (even in Sweden where I am)

Comment: @Zombies Or you could try http://www.google.se/asdasdasdasd. I geuss that would always be the same, unless google creates that page. Highly unlikely tho

Comment: @>Zombies Great, I think that my last comment is more fitting tho

Answer (score 3):

It might not be obvious; but http://example.com, http://example.net and http://example.org are actual, real sites; the might suit your needs.

**Edit:** I'm not sure about the specifics of their uptime stats and IP address, but I imagine these things, as well as the contents, are completely and utterly static.

Comment: I like the fact they exist! and one can assume that they will never change, until they change.

Comment: They don't look as if they've changed a lot in the last 10 years; no reason to think the next 10 would be different.

Answer (score 1):

You could create your own website, at least then you will know that the content will never change and you you will know when its down?

Comment: Hm, I suppose I would need to find a host with good uptime, yes then that would match all criteria quite well.

Comment: Relying on a third party for testing purposes is a bit selfish and rude, unless you have an agreement with them.  Your own site is definitely the way to go.

Comment: I do not think it is rude if you only test connectivity. I think google can take it :)

Comment: You could also just get the content from google.com (whether it redirects or not) and look for the existence some content that will be unique to google eg "window.google" (found doing a view source)

Comment: Another idea could be to check more than one site that you would expect to be up?